# How to install Chrome Extension programmatically through msi package via enterprise or group pollicy

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, windows-7, wix, group-policy

I have a Chrome Extension hosted on Chrome Web Store for my users. I have already tested it installing programmatically with WiX through writing at Windows registry under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions\<ID>`, but I don't want to do that, rather I need to write it under `Software\Policies\Chromium\ExtensionInstallForcelist` as described at Chromium developer site, so that the extension cannot be removed or disabled. But I understand now that directly writing it to the registry does not do the needful anymore and the extension is not installed and no policy is found under chrome://policy.

Please help me with the solution? Or if the registry entry needs to be through group policy, how can I do that?

***Edit:***
I was going through the following links, one is [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188446?hl=en), and came to know little further about the two types of policies, machine policy and cloud-based policy. I need to know the "machine policy" way and that to programmatically, so that I can distribute my .msi package built through WiX to my users for installation on their machines. My .msi package should silently force install the chrome extension (being hosted on chrome web store) through group policy, so that it will be non-removable and the extension will work for any user **regardless of their being signed in into chrome**.

Finding the solution would be of great help for me. To do this, I can learn whatever I need to. Please help.

Comment: It's called "Enterprise" for a reason. Only machines that are part of a Windows Domain can get that, and only a domain administrator can adjust it. An installer has no hopes of affecting that.

Comment: not really. its doable from the gapps admin.google.com page. ive done it before.

Comment: Please help about how it can be done through Google Admin Console. Any way I need to do this. Please help.

Comment: I think people are developing apps with "force install" for legitimate reasons, so I hope I am not requesting anything wrong. @ZigMandel, Is their anything that I should not know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done directly from the google apps admin console. The original question requests a way to do it through Registry, but then in a comment it was asked how to do it the way I proposed. Here it is 
enter https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?fral=1#ServiceSettings/service=chrome+os&subtab=usersettings
then clik on "Manage pre-installed apps", search it in the chrome store and add it.

Note that this only works when the user is signed-in to chrome using their gapps account.

Comment: +1, since it was requested in the comments, but note that the question itself does not say Google Apps anywhere. It refers to GPO installs.

Comment: yes but the askwr was mislead in the registry way. later he accepts this alternative and asks how to do so.

Comment: @ZigMandel, really appreciate what I learned from your answer. Actually the confusion is happening due to my insufficient knowledge in this domain. Please forgive me for that. I have edited my question now. Please consider it. Xan, please see if the edit can better explain and you can provide a solution.

Comment: I am really struggling for the solution here. Any help is highly appreciated. @ZigMandel, earlier I commented so because you wrote "not really. its doable from the gapps admin.google.com page. ive done it before." after Xan's comment. I thought it was doable through registry that way from admin.google.com, since I truly had least knowledge about the policy thing. Could you please reconsider helping a bit.

Comment: i dont know how to do it by registry. I proposed doing it from the admin console.